# MVC4 custom build error Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, customization

I'm trying to do a custom build for MVC4, this for educational purpose rather than project.

I get the code from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

compiled fine, make a small change, get the output System.Web.Mvc and inject it in my project.

I removed the references for System.Web.Mvc from my project and linked to the custom one.
I always get this error

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)`

I used the sn tool to ignore the dll verification and make sure it has been added to the registry

I changed the web.config

```
`<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>`
```

make it like this

```
`<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>`
```

I even tried to remove the above code from the web.config
non of these worked out.

what I want to achieve is to see the new behaviour I created in my custom build System.Web.Mvc

I'm using windows 7 X64 , and vs.net 2012